shortkey for dashes in scripts in vscode
I usually using "#--------------------------------------------------" as section seperator when writing python or R scripts in VSCode.
Is there any shortcut that allow to set shortkey for this kind of 'text'?
I try to add some function to json file but it does not work

Type "Preferences: Configure User Snippets" in the Command Palette. Choose the language for which you want to create the snippet. Add a new snippet definition in the JSON file that opens. Then you can create the custom key binding. In CP: "Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON)". Make sure to reload VSCode before testing it.
"Section Separator": {
  "prefix": "sectionsep",
  "body": [
    "#--------------------------------------------------"
  ],
  "description": "Insert section separator"
}

and keybindings.json :
[
  {
    "key": "ctrl+alt+s",
    "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
    "args": {
      "name": "Section Separator"
    },
    "when": "editorLangId == python"
  }
]


hi, what do you mean in "In CP: "Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON)"."?

in the Command palette (ctrl+shift+p) type "Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON)"

i added some edits, maybe that could help you!

@ParSaMnS This also needs to apply to the R language.  You should modify the when clause to handle both cases.  Also, for so simple a snippet I suggest just putting it into the keybinding without also defining it in a snippets file.

@Mark, True yeah. This is more logical...

hey it works, thank a lot

Happy to hear that! can you please confirm the answer? thank you very much
